# Automapping to extend a class

Tags: c#, .net-core, tuples, automapper

There are two classes:

```
public class User 
{
    public int id;
    public string username;
    //  lots more...
}

public class UserEx : User
{
    public string extraData;
}
```

And this is the CreateMap that is currently being used:

```
profile.CreateMap< Tuple<User, string>, UserEx>()
    .ForMember( d => d.id, opt => opt.MapFrom( s => s.Item1.id ) )
    .ForMember( d => d.username, opt => opt.MapFrom( s => s.Item1.username ) )
// lots and lots more mappings of s.Item1 to d
    .ForMember( d => d.extraData, opt => opt.MapFrom( s => s.Item2.extraData ) );
```

The User class has a ton of fields, is there some automatic way to get it to map s.Item1 to the destination?

---

I did look at the doc's on flattening > IncludeMembers and came up with the following which does NOT work:

```
      .Ignore( d => d.extraData );

profile.CreateMap< Tuple<User, string>, UserEx>()
     .IncludeMembers( t => t.Item1 )
     .ForMember( d => d.extraData, opt => opt.MapFrom( s => s.Item2.extraData ) );
```

Comment: Have you tried mapping `User` to `UserEx` and *not* specifying the members explicitly? AutoMapper was created to remove explicit field assignments, by matching fields based on conventions, including names. Otherwise that mapping would only be a more cumbersome and slower version of a simple `return new UserEx { extaData=user.extraData,id=user.id,...})`.

Comment: If you want to map the first item of a tuple call `Map` on that, not the entire tuple. Given the names, `profile.CreateMap<User, UserEx>()` should work.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu tried that and posted the results of what I tried, which did not work in the OP.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hear what you are saying and it make sense, here is the catch:  I am using the map in the select section of a LINQ statement that is joining the user list with the extra data.  I will play with things to see if I can figure out how to build in the select.

Comment: Post the actual code. EF Core doesn't return tuples. Neither does LINQ. It's the query that generated those tuples. Using AutoMapper in an EF LINQ query should modify the query itself and return only the data needed by the *target type*. I doubt mapping a tuple can be translated to SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already found a solution, based on what you initially said.  I created a local function that takes the User and extra data, uses the mapper to create the UserEx from the User, then updates the extra data manually before returning the object.  While not as clean as I like, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @PanagiotisKanavos's and kept it simple:

```
profile.CreateMap< User, UserEx>()
    .Ignore( d => d.extraData );

UserEx MakeUserEx(User u, string extraData)
{
    var userEx = mapper.Map<UserEx>(u);
    userEx.extraData = extraData;
    return userEx;
}

var listOfUserEx = from u in UserList
join ex in extraDataList on u.id equals ex.id
select MakeUserEx(u, ex.extraData)
```

I tried to figure out how to make the MakeUser a lambda function, but this works well and after a bit I figured it was time to move on.